# Constrained optimization of positive definite quadratic form

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-programming, hessian-matrix

Let $Q$ be an $n×n$ symmetric positive definite matrix, $a,b \in \mathbb{R^n}$, and $c \in \mathbb{R}$.  Assume all $a_i$, all $b_j$, and $c$ are positive. Also note that $x \geq 0$ means $x_i \geq 0$ for all $i$. Minimize $\frac{1}{2}x^TQx-b^Tx$ subject to $a^Tx \leq c, x > 0$.

Find the candidate(s) for minimizers using the $1^{st}$ order conditions and check whether they satisfy the $2^{nd}$ order conditions.

I know how to work with minimization problems and inequalities given functions but I'm not sure how to determine the $1^{st}$ and $2^{nd}$ order conditions for the above question

Comment: the KKT conditions are your best bet

Comment: Right so that was my underlying assumption but I don't understand how I represent the first order derivative of the matrix for the KKT condition.

Comment: $d/dx x^T A x = 2Ax$

Comment: Are particular $Q$, $a$, $b$, $c$ given?

Comment: No I believe the concept is to find a general solution to the problem, which is why I'm finding it a little tricky